# how to put restriction on the final user can't exatrct the apk and get code of your app?

Tags: android

how to put restriction on the final user can't exatrct the apk and get the sourcecode of your app I google very much but i get the solution as use of proguard? but it won't works fine? Still i can get the whole code from apk.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't do anything that is 100% effective. Proguard helps but just makes the probability lower by making piecing together your code, much more difficult to the average person. Mostly think about, is it really going to happen, and if so, what is the impact?

Comment: I can get the code from apk using the "dex2jar" and get the resources from the "apktool" after using the progaurd?Then please give me some idea to use the proguard in proper way.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can do all of those. All proguard will do is instead of having code from dex2jar as `public void myMethod(String name)` you will have code like `public void a(String a)`

Comment: Again it's not 100% but just enable the default proguard if you are uncertain, but be sure to whitelist the android sdk and any 3rd party libs you may be depending on which are in binary form or that rely on anything outside what is imported in your buildable project